# How to know if an email id is for a group or an individual?

Tags: office365, outlook-addin

We are building an Outlook Office 365 JS add-in and we need to know how many people will receive the email.

Is there a way to know if an email id is a group or individual? Also, will it be possible to get the number of email addresses in the group?

Comment: Is that a JS or a COM addin?

Comment: It is a JS addin.